# Apple route points or google route points on apple maps

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps, mapkit

It is against the policy of Google maps to show GOOGLE Route on any other maps except Google maps.I am using apple maps and i want to show route between two points. Lets say current location and some other point

From another stack flow question I saw this query

```
NSString* apiUrlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.apple.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=%@&destination=%@&sensor=false", saddr, daddr];
```

However it seems that this query redirects you to google maps instead when tried on browser. If anyone can confirm I can use its data on apple maps or is it against policy?

Comment: One would think that if the data is coming from Google, and if Google's terms of use prevent you from displaying that data on non-Google maps, then you shouldn't display that data on non-Google maps.

Comment: This happens in desktop.http://techcrunch.com/2012/09/22/mapsception/ read this

Comment: try this...http://rajneesh071.blogspot.in/2013/03/show-route-from-current-location-to.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not give the user an option. If the user wants to open on MAPS then they can select a button and another button for Google Maps which you can force to open on Safari.

Comment: I want to get an array of route points between two geo locations. If there is another solute, i would love to find out.

Comment: I know I am saying show both with a button to switch between points. Also remember that if you use the google API its metered meaning if you use it in production you run the risk of google turning your access off if you dont pay them fees.